# DAX change calculate order

Tags: dax

I have a table with information about tasks (you can see below). I'm trying to get a number of unique TaskID where IsOverdued is "Yes". I used this formula:

```
UniqueIsOverdued = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Table[TaskID]);
    Table[IsOverdued]="Yes"
)
```

But I got wrong result because firstly the table was filtered by `IsOverdued="Yes"` and only then by unique TaskID. So in my example it would result "3" but I need it to be "2".

Please advise how to correct this formula to achieve the desired result.

[image: Table example - click to view]

Comment: With your DataSet and following formula (Measure_1 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[TaskID]), 'Table'[overdue]="Yes")) its working on my site. So I have the result of 2 TaskIDs. Did you really choose a measure and not calculated column ?

Comment: The table that you showed in your question is a bit confusing, because it only shows two distinct TaskIDs anyway, so where are you getting 3 from? Maybe show us the whole table.